# objective c to swift conversion. (#define and weak)

Tags: objective-c, swift, weak

I am stuck in converting #define and weak from objective c to swift. I tried to use objective c to swift convertor, but I think the result of conversion is not correct.

```
#define WeakRef(__obj) __weak typeof(self) __obj = self
#define WeakReturn(__obj) if(__obj ==nil)return;
WeakRef(weakSelf);
WeakReturn(weakSelf);
```

For the second, third and forth lines, I think it should be something like this in Swift

```
func WeakReturn(obj: Any?) {
    if obj == nil {
        return
    }
}
WeakRef(self)
WeakReturn(self)
```

In my guess for the first line, it first check the condition of `typeof(self) == ??`. If true, then set the pointer (__obj) to self. But, I am not sure about what ?? should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WeakRef` simply gives you a weak reference to some object, and in Swift, that's just `weak var foo = obj`; it doesn't need a utility method.

`WeakReturn` can't be replicated in Swift, because the Obj-C macro is used to insert a conditional return in a function. There are no macros in Swift, and the Swift `WeakReturn` function that you defined does absolutely nothing--it returns whether the object is `nil` or not; all you've done is make one of those returns explicit. My guess is that this macro was added to the Obj-C code to save some lazy programmer from writing `if obj == nil return;`.

Comment: so weakSelf is just self in Swift?

Comment: No; `weak var foo = obj` is weakSelf in Swift.